# i cant update or insert values in my database using mysql and flask furthermore no error in my code when i run it

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

sorry for the question being long please look in the function register i can access only the values present in database but i cant insert values using this function please look over this issue

furthermore i am not getting any error when tried to register

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for,session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re

app=Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'your secret key'
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'nfjkngk'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'test'

mysql = MySQL(app)




@app.route('/register', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'mail_id' in request.form and 'passwd' in request.form and 'P_name' in request.form and 'age' in request.form and 'blood_group' in request.form and 'sex' in request.form :
        conn=mysql.connect
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        mail_id = request.form['mail_id']
        passwd = request.form['passwd']
        P_name = request.form['P_name']
        age = request.form['age']
        blood_group = request.form['blood_group']
        sex=request.form['sex']
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM patient WHERE mail_id = % s', (mail_id, ))
        patient = cursor.fetchone()
        if patient:
            msg = 'Account already exists !'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', mail_id):
            msg = 'Invalid email address !'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO patient VALUES (NULL, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s)', (mail_id, passwd, P_name, age, blood_group, sex,))
            conn.commit()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered !'
            return redirect(url_for('index.html'))
    else:
        msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
    return render_template('register.html', msg = msg)

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        return render_template("index.html")
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug=True
    app.run(host ="localhost", port = int("5000"))
```

Answer (score 0):

After ready flask_sql [documentation](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I can clearly see that flask_sql is just in the initial stages of development and is not yet mature enough to be recommended for development. So for better results, I will recommend sqlAlchemy or [MySQLdb](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#).

The only thing that seems wrong is the below statement from your code:

```
 cursor.execute('INSERT INTO patient VALUES (NULL, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s)', (mail_id, passwd, P_name, age, blood_group, sex,))
```

The correct version of the above statement will be without `%` space `s` and including an index_id:

```
 cursor.execute('INSERT INTO patient VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (index_id, mail_id, passwd, P_name, age, blood_group, sex,))
```

These are not syntax errors so that is why you are not getting an error.

Comment: it worked fine and flask_mysqldb is somewhat easy to handle for me i made a small mistake in my html file and the code which i have posted is correct and there is no need of id

Answer (score 0):

It maybe easy if you use **SQLAlchemy** it's the best for flask and easy to use